# Count Number of unique users which loggedin more than Once

Tags: mysql, count

I have multiple websites run on single database.

My question related table Structure is like here:

```
USER
    - UserID
WEBSITE
    - WebsiteID
        - WebsiteName
LOGINRECORD
    - UserID
    - WebsiteID
    - LoginDate
```

I want to Count Number of unique users which loggedin more than ones by webssite.

Like

```
Website          NumberofUserLoggedinMorethanOnce 
abc.com                     15 
def.com                     25
```

Comment: Use MySQL stored sessions, then a `mysql_num_rows()` for the Website you want.

Comment: @Frederick Marcoux: it is really terrible advice

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I just try first one, it works well so i accept it :) I upvoted all answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: I misunderstood the question. This should be it:

```
SELECT WEBSITE.WebsiteName, count(*)
FROM WEBSITE 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT UserID, WebsiteID, count(*) FROM LOGINRECORD
GROUP BY UserID, WebsiteID
HAVING count(*) > 1) AS T1 ON t1.WebsiteID = WEBSITE.WebsiteID
GROUP BY WEBSITE.WebsiteName
```

Comment: Group by website+user, not just user (and use nested query)

Comment: Klaus Byskov Hoffmann, this is not what i want. I want get number of users who loggedin multiple times per website.

Comment: @zerkms yup, I get it (now ;-))

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT WebsiteID,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM (SELECT WebsiteID
          FROM LOGINRECORD
      GROUP BY WebsiteID,
               UserID
        HAVING count(*) > 1) x
GROUP BY WebsiteID
```

Comment: You don't have the website name ;-P

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but give this a go -

```
select websitename, count(*)
from website
inner join
(
select userid, websiteid, count(*)
from loginrecord
inner join website on loginrecord.websiteid = website.websiteid
group by userid, websiteid
having count(*) > 1
) tbl
on tbl.websiteid = website.websiteid
group by websitename
```